# Angular FormGroup ignores my standard value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I have already some standard values coming from my web api in my form. The problem is my FromGroup ignores them and sets all the values to null. A value is only not null if i type something by myself into the input. So if im trying to update a user it would reset the whole user.

My Form:

```html
<form [formGroup]="persoForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

            <div id="firma">
                <mat-form-field appearance="standard" id="firm" floatLabel="always">
                    <mat-label> Firmenbez.:</mat-label>
                    <input matInput type="text" name="firm" formControlName="firmenBez" [value]="person.firmenbezeichnung"/>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
</form>
```

TS

```html
persoForm = new FormGroup({
    firmenBez: new FormControl(),
  })
```

```html
onSubmit(){ //currently only there to check if the values are still null
      
      console.log(this.persoForm.getRawValue());
}
```

Comment: build the formgroup first, then fetch the data from the webservice and update the formgroup with pathValue() or setValue(). Why do you have a [value]? Reactive Forms do all for you.

Comment: I thought [value] would be right if i want to show a existing value in my input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` should take the value from one source, but you're using two sources in your code: one of them is the `formControlName` and the other one is `value`.

In Angular Reactive Form, you have to keep the `formControlName` without `value`, and handle its value based on your API data:

- If you get the data before initializing the `FormGroup`, then you have to initialize it like the following:

```js
// init the form-group when you get the data from the API like the following:
this.personForm = new FormGroup({
  firmenBez: new FormControl(this.person.firmenbezeichnung),
});
```

- But if you get the date after initializing the `FormGroup`, you can keep your initialization as is it, then patch the data comes from the API like the following:

```js
onDataReceived(person) {
  this.personForm.patchValue({
    firmenBez: person.firmenbezeichnung,
  });
}
```

Comment: I did it now with a new function which patches all the values into the formGroup. If i delete the [value] it looses the text in the input.

Comment: Do you mean it's not working, even with the description I added to the answer?

Comment: Sure it works, but in my case a [value] is more useful :) Im just saving user data, so setting with thebutton the userdata is not efficient as just setting [value] and initalize it from start. The patchValue thing works, thx